# Assigning variable of Class<> Type implementing an interface in Java

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a variable of type `Class`, which implements some interface.

Like:

```
Class<List<String>> b = ArrayList.class;
```

But when i try something like this, it complains about incompatible types, since the generics is filled with the concrete class.

Is there a way to do this?

I want to do this to be type safe further down the road. I know that it will work when i don't care about type safety, but if i could, I would rather do it in a type safe manner.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on in what circumstances you might need the Class variable? I cannot imagine a type safety case that requires that.

Comment: I think you can't get the variable of type class which implements your interface.

Comment: @aviad I will use this class for calling a Builder that is based on reflection. It is a generic builder that accepts any implementation of an interface. In the start method it gets the class, fills some data and then calls the constructor via reflection on the class.

Comment: The best I can do is `Class<? extends List> b = ArrayList.class;`

Comment: @Xtroce try to use Visitor pattern. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor

Comment: The moment you start using reflection to construct generic instances, there is no more type safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use `Class<List<String>> b = (Class)ArrayList.class;`. It compiles, doesn't throw an exception and gives type safety.

The reason you can't just use `Class<List<String>> b = ArrayList.class;` is because `ArrayList.class` isn't a `Class<List<String>>` type, but rather a primitive `class` type. Casting it to `Class` removes the primitive and wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

You get a type error here `Class<List<String>> b = ArrayList.class;` 'couse ArrayList.class is not Class>. Why? Let's see, Think about lists, in their implementatios they look like

```
public interface List<T> ...
```

So, when you create a List, you MUST tell her wich is his type inside, for example:

```
List<String> list1;
List<Integer> list2;
```

the original error is similar to:

```
List<String> list1 = new String("Hi");
List<Integer> list2 = new Integer(5);
```

The correct way, is telling both types, that creates a new concrete type:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

list1 and list2, don't have the same type, although they both are List.

Finally, for your class "Class", the correct way is to do something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Class<T> {

    private T v;

    public Class(T t){
        this.v = t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Class<List<String>> a = new Class<List<String>>(list);
    }

}
```